I need help to evaluate Integral :$I=\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\arctan^2(\sin(x))}{1+\cos(x)}dx$
I need  help to evaluate Integral :$$I=\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\arctan^2(\sin(x))}{1+\cos(x)}dx$$
All the tricks I know didn't work.  I know that it is my duty to try, but this integration is difficult. I could not find the solution even though I spent a lot of time trying it.

Do we have to understand $\arctan^2(y)$ as $\arctan(y)^2$ or $\arctan(\arctan(y))$?

What makes you think this has a closed form?

Do you mean
$\int_0^{\pi} \arctan^2\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)}\right)dx$?

If the answer to @RobertZ 's question is yes, see here

I think @Quanto has a nice idea to do such integrals.. let's wait and see

I never thought this would have closed form, but turns out everything works out in a very complicated, yet nice, way.
First you can shift the integral and use the symmetry to get
$$
I = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{\arctan(\cos(x))^2}{1-\sin(x)}\text dx = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{\arctan(\cos(x))^2}{1+\sin(x)}\text dx
$$
So if we sum both equalities, we obtain
\begin{align}
2I &= \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \arctan(\cos(x))^2 \left(\frac{1}{1+\sin(x)} + \frac{1}{1-\sin(x)} \right)\text dx \\
&= 2\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}  \frac{\arctan(\cos(x))^2}{1-\sin(x)^2}\text dx = 4\int_0^{\pi/2}  \left(\frac{\arctan(\cos(x))}{\cos(x)}\right)^2\text dx.
\end{align}
Because
$$
\frac{\arctan(x)}{x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} x^{2n},
$$
By the Cauchy product,
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}\right)^2
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{2n} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{(2k+1)(2(n-k)+1)} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{2n+2} \sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{1}{2k+1} + \frac{1}{2(n-k)+1}\right) \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{n+1} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2k+1}.
\end{align}
For later use, we recall the generating function for the Catalan numbers
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n+1} \binom{2n}{n} = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}
$$
Hence, using Wallis integrals
\begin{align}
I &= 2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1} \left(\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(x)^{2n} \text dx\right) \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2k+1} \\
&= \pi \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1} \binom{2n}{n} \frac{1}{4^n} \sum_{k=0}^n \int_0^1 x^{2k} \text dx \\
&= \pi \int_0^1 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1/4)^n}{n+1} \binom{2n}{n}\frac{x^{2n+2}-1}{x^2-1} \text dx \\
&= \pi \int_0^1 \frac{2(\sqrt{1+x^2}-1)-2(\sqrt{2}-1)}{x^2-1} \text dx \\
&= 2\pi \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-\sqrt{2}}{x^2-1} \text dx = 2\pi \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}+\sqrt{2}} \text dx.
\end{align}
Wolfram alpha outputs the final value
$$
I = \pi (2\log(1+\sqrt2)-\sqrt2\log2) \approx 2.45826178996,
$$
while also giving
$$
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}+\sqrt{2}} \text dx = \frac{\sqrt2}{2} \log\left(\frac{\sqrt{2x^2+2}-x+1}{\sqrt{2x^2+2}+x+1}\right) + \text{arcsinh}(x) + C.
$$

Very clever use of series. I think we might be able to manage an antiderivative too using complex dilogarithms.

Very nice solution

More than inspired by @Nolord elegant solution.
$$I = 2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1} \left(\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(x)^{2n} \,dx\right) \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2k+1}$$
Using
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(x)^{2n} \,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\,\, \Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2\, \Gamma(n+1)}\quad \text{if} \quad n>0$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2k+1}=\frac{1}{2}H_{n+\frac{1}{2}}+\log (2)$$
$$I=\pi+\frac {\sqrt\pi}2\,\, \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\, \frac{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma
   (n+2)}\,\, \left(H_{n+\frac{1}{2}}+2 \log
   (2)\right)$$
Using
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\, \frac{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma
   (n+2)}\,\, H_{n+\frac{1}{2}}=-2 \sqrt{\pi } \left(1+3
   \left(\sqrt{2}-1\right) \log(2)+\log \left(3-2
   \sqrt{2}\right)\right)$$ and
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\, \frac{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(n+2)}=\left(2 \sqrt{2}-3\right) \sqrt{\pi }$$
Then
$$I=-\pi  \big(\sqrt{2} \log (2)+\log
   \left(3-2 \sqrt{2}\right)\big)$$

Fold up $I$ like Nolord suggested, then integrate by parts to reduce the power of $\arctan$, which can then be replaced with its integral representation. Swap the variables with Fubini and evaluate to recover the same elementary integral.
$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^\pi \frac{\arctan^2(\sin x)}{1+\cos x} \, dx \\
&= 2 \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \frac{\arctan^2(\cos x)}{\cos^2x} \, dx \\
&= 4 \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \frac{\sin^2x \arctan(\cos x)}{\cos x \left(1+\cos^2x\right)} \, dx & \rm IBP \\
&= 4 \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \int_0^1 \frac{\sin^2x}{\left(1+\cos^2x\right)\left(1+y^2\cos^2x\right)} \, dy \, dx \\
&= 4 \int_0^1 \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \frac{1-c^2}{\left(1+c^2\right)\left(1+y^2c^2\right)} \, dx \, dy & [c=\cos x] \\
&= 4 \int_0^1 \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \left(\frac{\frac2{1-y^2}}{1+\cos^2x} - \frac{\frac{1+y^2}{1-y^2}}{1+y^2\cos^2x}\right) \, dx \, dy \\
&= 4 \int_0^1 \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \left(\frac{\frac2{1-y^2}}{2+\tan^2x} - \frac{\frac{1+y^2}{1-y^2}}{1+y^2+\tan^2x}\right) \, d(\tan x) \, dy \\
&= 2\pi \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{y^2+1} - \sqrt2}{y^2-1} \, dy
\end{align*}$$

Very nice. I wondered if it was possible not to go through summations to recover the last integral, but apparently we can! Even though my method still seems the more natural (I gave it to a friend, and he solved it the exact same way I did).
